# Apache2 mod_python Error...?

Tags: python, apache2, 22.04

Clean install Of Jellyfish 22.04
is anyone else getting this error in their Apache logs?

python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '3.10.2', found '3.10.4'.
python_init: Python executable found '(null)'.
python_init: Python path being used '(null)'.

tried re-installing mod,
apt remove libapache2-mod-python
apt install libapache2-mod-python

Same error
Seems like everything works... just want to make sure

Thanks